# Direct deploy from unity to hololens emulator

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

Is there any way to direct install from unity to hololens emulator ?
I want to hit unity play button and hololens app get install and run on emulator.

Its very hard to for each test build unity project and then run built visual studio project on emulator.

I also used Mixed Reality Portal but it doesn't show real scales, scales are very smaller than hololens device.

Comment: Hi, I have provided a solution, does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can try the Holographic Emulation feature provided by unity(https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/windowsholographic-emulation.html), and download the Holographic Remoting Player from the store in the simulator.

After successfully connecting to your simulator, you can run the Microsoft HoloLens project directly in the Unity editor rather than building and running the game each time you want to see the effects of the changes.